# .NET 6 how to add pages numbers in the view?

Tags: pagination, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I am following the Microsoft tutorial :
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-6.0
and it works but there is only the button for next and previous...
How to implement the code with the list of the pages numbers between the NEXT and PREVIOUS button?

I created thi code, but i am sure that there is a better way to accomplish this :

```
    <a asp-action="Index"
   asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
   asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex - 1)"
   asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
   class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled">
    Previous
</a>

@for (int i = 1; i < Model.TotalPages + 1; i++)
{
    if (Model.PageIndex == i)
    {
        <b>@i.ToString()</b>
    }
    else
    {
        <a asp-action="Index"
   asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
   asp-route-pageNumber="@i.ToString()"
   asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
   class="btn btn-default">
            @i.ToString()
        </a>
    }
}

<a asp-action="Index"
   asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
   asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex + 1)"
   asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
   class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled">
    Next
</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try LazZiya.TagHelpers .you can find it through Nuget .

Use it in cshtml:

```
@addTagHelper *,LazZiya.TagHelpers





<paging page-no="Model.PageIndex"

        page-size="Model.Pagesize"
        total-records="Model.TotalRecords"  
 >
</paging>
```

codes in model:

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }
        public  int  Pagesize { get; private set; }

        public int TotalRecords { get; private set; }

        public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            PageIndex = pageIndex;
            TotalRecords = count;
            Pagesize = pageSize;
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
           
            this.AddRange(items);
        }

        public bool HasPreviousPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex > 1);
            }
        }

        public bool HasNextPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
            }
        }

        public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = await source.CountAsync();
            var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
            return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
    }
```

codes in controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder,string currentFilter,string searchString,int? P)
        {
            ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;
            ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                P = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;
            var students = from s in _context.Student
                           select s;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                students = students.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString)
                                       || s.FirstMiddleName.Contains(searchString));
            }
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    students = students.OrderBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
                    break;
                case "date_desc":
                    students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
                    break;
                default:
                    students = students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
                    break;
            }
            int pageSize = 3;
           
            return View(await PaginatedList<Student>.CreateAsync(students.AsNoTracking(), P ?? 1, pageSize));
        }
```

And The result:
[image]